# auto resizing iframe height according to content

Tags: html, iframe

I am new to html. I tried many codes about resizing iframes. But any code didn't work on my project. I am working on Dreamweaver and xhtml 1.0. I included iframe on my Index web page (index.html). Now I want to open the Home page(Home.html), Services.html, etc.. in the iframe. The home.html and other pages opens in the iframe but the iframe doesn't resize according to the content of these pages. Please provide me a working code if anyone knows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Pink Maid Beauty Salon | Home</title>
</head><link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("navigationbar", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>

<body>

<!--Background-->
<div class="body">

<!--Header-->
<div id="header"></div>

<!--Logo-->
<div id="logo"></div>

<!--Menu-->
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#home">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#news">Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#contact">Cart <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--Navigation-->
<div id="navigation">
  <ul id="navigationbar" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a href="Home.html" target="content">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html" target="content">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html" target="content">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Us.html" target="content">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact Us.html" target="content">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--Content-->
<iframe src="Home.html" name="content" frameborder="0">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use spry it has been abandoned by Adobe for years. Use jQuery it's not going anywhere soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as simple a problem as it should be. I wrote a js lib that tackles this problem that you might find useful.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Please explain me how to use these js lib. @David Bradshaw

Comment: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#typical-setup and then add iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js to the page in the iFrame.

Comment: It isn't working sir. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Sir it worked. I tried your js library by studying example web pages. It worked sir. Thank you so much. Now I can complete my project. :-D

Comment: This library doesn't work on GoogleForms embeded. It resizes to a small height